# RTT (Round Trip Time) always return Zero in Unity DOTs Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking, unity-dots

I'm trying to use the DOTsSample Unity project and want to use this NetworkStatistics Class
(https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/DOTSSample/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Game/Main/NetworkStatisticsClient.cs)
and trying to write a script to show the network statistics in my game, but the thing is it always returns 0.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NetStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update


    NetworkStatisticsClient networkStatisticsClient;
    private SocketTransport m_Transport;
    private NetworkClient m_NetworkClient;

    void Start()
    {

        m_Transport = new SocketTransport();
        m_Transport.Connect("127.0.0.1",80);

        m_NetworkClient = new NetworkClient(m_Transport);

        if (Application.isEditor || Game.game.buildId == "AutoBuild")
            NetworkClient.clientVerifyProtocol.Value = "0";

        m_NetworkClient.UpdateClientConfig();
        networkStatisticsClient = new NetworkStatisticsClient(m_NetworkClient);


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Client isConnected is False thus, the connection is not establishment is not correct
        Debug.Log("Rtt: " +  m_NetworkClient.isConnected + networkStatisticsClient.rtt.average);
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, I would expect you to connect to a server somewhere in the start function.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkClient.Connect.html

```
    public void Start()
    {
        myClient = NetworkClient.Instance;

        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.SYSTEM_CONNECT, OnConnected);
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.SYSTEM_DISCONNECT, OnDisconnected);
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.SYSTEM_ERROR, OnError);
        // this line here is important
        myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    }
```

The network client is used to make rpc calls to a server. It's not a generic client medically abstracting all network connectivity.

Comment: the code you shared is from the older version of the unity. I'm using DOTS Sample and with a custom NetworkClient Implementation

Comment: Edited the Question but the problem persists

Comment: Check again the link. You need to call the connect on the instance.

Comment: It seems to be the issue with the net code version I was using. I can't manually connect in the script. It gives the value when I use it in the Multiplayer Playmode settings as Client&Server